# Magento installation stuck by "Module 'Magento_Indexer': Running recurring.." at 36% on suse12

Tags: magento2

I am installing magento from chrome browser.

My php version is as follow
$php --version

```
PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2016 05:17:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Mysql version is as follow 
$/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --version

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.29, for Linux (s390x) using  EditLine wrapper
```

During installation at step6.
Upto 36% it shows progress and stops at Module `'Magento_Indexer': Running recurring.`. then the progress comes back to 0%. Then It goes to 36%. It has the following console log at the end:

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running recurring..
```

solutions tried :

1. max_execution_time = 20000 
   max_input_time = 20000 mysql.connect_timeout = -1 can you set this in php.ini.

Still shows the same issue

Comment: I always installed m2 from console and offer the same to you. It's much faster and clearer

Answer (score 2):

Query against your database:

"SHOW PROCESSLIST"

There is probably a list of processes.
Try to kill them one by one if needed.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem the fix for me  `xdebug.max_nesting_level` to `200` in php ini.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_install-issues.html#known-devbeta-xdebug

Comment: the xdebug.max_nesting_level is not present in php.ini

Comment: check phpinfo it is there?

Comment: phpinfo not found. I checked sudo find / -name phpinfo

Comment: xdebug is not installed and not found in zypper search also

Comment: give 777 file permission i think problem with permission.

Comment: i have given 777 permission to whole magento folder

Comment: give recursive permission all folder inside the main folder and files too.

Comment: however php extension check and folder permission and mysql database check all are already passed.. I am getting error at last step

Comment: recurssive permission are given

Comment: any error it is diplaying?

Comment: same as the cosole.log as shown in question

Answer (score 1):

You can do installation using command line

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root  --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Magento 2 doesn't support PHP 5.5.9, try to update to PHP 5.5.22 or major ( I recommend the PHP 7.0.18).

Then try to run these commands:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf vendor/* var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vv ;
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

**PHP Versions Supported**

[image: PHP supported on Magento 2]

[Here's the reference on the DevDocs.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)